# Correct category attribute for inclusion in Topmenu -- is_active vs. include_in_menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, topmenu

Two attributes on the Category model seem possibly relevant to determining whether a category should be shown in the Topmenu: *Is Active* (`is_active`) and *Include in Navigation Menu* (`include_in_menu`).

Despite the seemingly obvious intended purpose for *Include in Navigation Menu*, a review of the code shows that Magento doesn't even check it when adding categories to the Topmenu--it only checks the `is_active` attribute.

Am I missing the point of the *Include in Navigation Menu* attribute, or is this potentially a bug?

For completeness, here's an overview of how I understand Magento's process of  rendering the Topmenu:

1. The `top.menu` block's `getHtml()` method is called.
2. The `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` event is fired to get items added to the block's $_menu attribute.
3. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::addCatalogToTopmenuItems` observes the event, retrieves the store's top-level categories, and calls its sibling method `_addCategoriesToMenu()` to add them to the menu.
4. `_addCategoriesToMenu()` recursively adds the categories and their subcategories to the menu, using `if (!$category->getIsActive()) { continue; }` to pass on categories that are not *active*, but does not check `include_in_menu` at all.
5. Back in the `top.Menu` block's `getHtml` method, the menu is rendered, either using a renderer class (if a `catalog.topnav.renderer` block is configured), or otherwise the default rendering method.

Aside from the question of whether categories must also be *Active* in order to appear, shouldn't `_addCategoriesToMenu` use `if (!$category->getIncludeInMenu()) { continue; }` instead?

Answer (score 1):

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree::addCollectionData` already sends only active and included in menu categories.

So in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::_addCategoriesToMenu` the `$categories` array is only formed by items that are active and included in the menu.

You can try in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree` to remove the line 159 `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1);` to disregard the filter if this is what you want.

At least, this is how I understand it.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, `addCollectionData` does add both `is_active` and `include_in_menu` filters to the entire set of categories returned. That throws a bit of a spanner in my plans, which I may move to a different question if I can't work it out. However, this question is really asking _what's the purpose_ of having two separate attributes if the `is_active` attribute is used to do the what the `include_in_menu` attribute seems better suited. Or, in code terms, _why_ does `addCollectionData`'s `$onlyActive` parameter result in filters on _both_ `is_active` _and_ `include_in_menu`?